# Ideas please for creating survey and/or a poll

Tags: add-on

I need to start making weekly “survey” but not sure what way is the best to go.

Wish for some idea how to be able to manage simple poll that it is easy to store to database and easy to look overall stats when times goes (for old poll’s/surveys).

Current survey/poll results available after their submit to see for all users and site visitors.

Idea is simple:

- Site: one question
- User input: one out of 3-5 available choices
- Note: no email or anything else user input needed
- Action: redirect to same page to show results so far.

Another in mind is:

- Site: One question
- User input: simple textarea to fill in.
- Note: email input available, not required.
- Actions: redirect to page that simply says “thank you for your answer”.

——

Data handling:
Admin-panel: easy access to collected data and results.

Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason this needs to be EE rather than a hosted service such as Survey Monkey which would give you everything you need with a fraction of the effort and costs?

Comment: Polls Addon, FreeForm could do it, but i would use thirdparty service like survey monkey, or even google forms.

Answer (score 0):

We've used Polls by EEHarbor - http://eeharbor.com/polls - seems to work OK and does everything you ask for. It's paid-for though. Integrates with various chart libraries and is skinnable. The documentation isn't amazing but they have been quite helpful with support.

The results are easily viewable in the admin end but there's no export which would be nice.